# How to pass a value to the HTML page with JavaScript redirection?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following function:

```
function loginUser(form){
  try {
    var user = Backendless.UserService.login(form.userid.value, form.pswrd.value);
    if (user != null) {
      window.location.href = "home.html";
    } else
      window.alert("Login failed");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    window.alert("Login failed. " + e.message);
  }
}
```

When I redirect to `home.html`, the user object has various fields and I want to pass the value of `user.credits` to an input box on the HTML page. How would I go about doing this?

This is what my HTML page looks like:

```
<div>Credits <input id="credits" type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Credits" name="credits"></div>
```

Comment: Pass it as a query parameter in the url.

Comment: Can you use `PHP`? `window.location.href = "home.php?some_val=a_val"`; Obviously I wouldn't do this if you're passing sensitive data.

Comment: Passing it as a url query will work but it is not recommended nor safe.. you can better do this using POST(through the backend) or using sessions or cookies.

Comment: Redirect to "home.html?credits=" + user.credits. On home.html get the parameter and put it in the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you coud do

```
window.location.href = "home.html?credits="+user.credits;
```

and on your `home.html` :

```
document.getElementById('credits').value=getUrlVars()["credits"];
```

You may want to read up a bit on the concept of GET and POST variables.
Also, notice this method is by no means safe: the user can easily manipulate the value.

A safer way would be to `POST` the values, or, better still, to read them, for example via PHP, on the target page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that worked thanks...

```
window.location.href = "home.html?credits="+user.credits;
```

and on your home.html :

```
document.getElementById('credits').value=getUrlVars()["credits"];
```

just needed the getUrlVars function as well

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, mark it. Marking is a good way to show appreciation for: Solving your problem / Answering your question.